# От какого класса наследуются все типы в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Сегодня меня спросили от какого класса наследуются все типы в Python?

Я не долго думая ответил, что от **object**

На что мне ответили, что от **object** наследуются в Python2, а в Python3 от **type**.

Пришел домой. Решил проверить. И обнаружил интересный момент:

```
class R():
    def __init__(self):
        name = 'MyCl'
a = R()

print(isinstance(a, type))         # False
print(isinstance(a, object))       # True
print(R.__mro__)                   # (<class '__main__.R'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Почему так получается? И почему **.**mro**** не показывает <class 'type'>?

Comment: Первый же вопрос, а почему вы уверены, что вам сказали верно?

Comment: @Сергей, ну это же на собеседовании было. Предполагаю, что на собеседовании сидят люди опытные от кампании...

Comment: `>>> isinstance(object() , type)
False`

Comment: "Опытный" не значит "не ошибающийся". Вот целый учебный курс от 2022 года, где ясно говорится про наследование от object.<https://www.yuripetrov.ru/edu/python/ch_10_01.html>

Comment: В вашем коде ошибка. Должно быть `a = R()`. Так все стает на свои места

Comment: Возможно, хотели определить как вы реагируете на неправоту начальника, готовы ли спорить и аргументировать свое мнение. Собеседования они не только (не столько) для определения знаний по специальности.

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA, исправил

Comment: В вопросе все еще смешаны два разных вывода из двух разных запусков разного кода. У экземпляра не бывает `__mro__`.

Comment: Теперь (после исправлений) с точки зрения кода противоречий нет -`type` не входит в иерархию наследования, это показывает и `isinstance` и `__mro__`.

Comment: Если вы так и не найдёте подтверждения идее наследования от `type`, то рекомендую связаться (например, вежливым письмом) с собеседовавшими и сообщить, что вы ничего не нашли, с просьбой всё же указать источник. Только не в стиле "вы не правы, хахаха", а "внимательно с интересом отношусь ко всему новому, постоянно развиваюсь. Не спорю сразу, не имея фактов, но возвращаюсь с вопросами или информацией, что во вводных возможна ошибка". Это покажет ваши хорошие soft skills. Зависит от культуры компании, конечно. Но нормальному руководителю должно понравиться, а ненормальный - зачем вам нужен?:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто проверить:

```py
!python -V
print(int.__base__)
print(type.__base__)
print(object.__base__)
```

Вывод:

```
Python 3.10.0
<class 'object'>
<class 'object'>
None
```

Итак, в `Pyhton 3.10` классы `int` и `type` - наследники `object`, при этом `object` не является ничьим наследником.

Так что всё как пишут в руководствах - в питоне всё наследуется от `object` рано или поздно, в том числе и `type`.